# DirSource Import file issue

Tags: r, tm

I have been trying to import the file

```
reuters <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = "E:\\R Programs\\Test\\Reuteurs\\reut2-000.xml", encoding = "UTF-8"), 
   readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))
```

However I get below error:

```
Error in DirSource(directory = "E:\\R Programs\\Test\\Reuteurs\\reut2-000.xml",  : 
  empty directory
```

I have also checked other solutions provide in stackoverflow but its not working for me. Am I missing anything?

But below code works: Why DirSource method is not working for me? Am I missing anything?

```
reuters <- Corpus(URISource("file://E:\\R Programs\\Test\\Reuteurs\\reut2-000.xml",encoding="UTF-8"), 
   readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))
```

Reference link which I referred:

[R: Got problems in reading text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643925/r-got-problems-in-reading-text-file)

[Using R for Text Mining Reuters-21578](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184541/using-r-for-text-mining-reuters-21578)

[R Error in trying to access local data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138241/r-error-in-trying-to-access-local-data)

Comment: have you tried to first locate on the right folder with `setwd()` and then use only the name of the file ?

Comment: Yes, I have done it.

Comment: `DirSource` does not look for a specific file but a directory. Look at `?DirSource` and try `DirSource(directory = "E:\\R Programs\\Test\\Reuteurs", ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reut2-000.xml` probably is a **file, and not a directory**?

Opening a file as directory will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the preprocessed Reuters Corpus from R package `tm.corpus.Reuters21578` (as I've already recommended here: [Using R for Text Mining Reuters-21578](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184541/using-r-for-text-mining-reuters-21578)).

```
install.packages("tm.corpus.Reuters21578", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at")
library(tm.corpus.Reuters21578)
data(Reuters21578)
```

These are the same data as in the original Reuters xml files, however without the issues with encoding, missing xml declaration etc.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a way out to this error:

words<-Corpus(VectorSource(fread(file,encoding = 'UTF-8',sep = ',',verbose = TRUE)))

hope this helps